# KitKat is not playing html 5 mp4 video packaged in cordova

Tags: html, cordova, video, mp4, android-4.4-kitkat

I am loading a video tag in html5 and packaging it into APK using cordova.
The generated Apk is not playing the mp4 video at all, it used to play in Jelly bean but now i am using kitkat which is not playing mp4 videos.
Even the stock kitkat browser failed to play the mp4 video or webm video. The video is loaded from remote.

I have also enabled hardware acceleration in my manifest file.

Am I doing something wrong or that is how things are? Kindly someone solve this. Here is my html video which is quite basic.

```
      <video width="850" height="550" controls>
      <source src="media/holders/howTo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="media/holders/howTo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
       Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
```

Comment: looks like there is something wrong with IIS server, when I apache server, this issue got resolved, thanks for everyone who viewed this. thanks.

Comment: Also, this issue got resolved in the IIS as well when I moved that content from the password protected folder in the server.